# FluentValidation documenting validator rules

Tags: fluentvalidation

I have inherited a lot of FluentValidation validators that I need to document and test.  The documentation needs to contain model, propertyName, Min/max Length, Null/ Not Null, Min/Max Values, Error Message
I am trying to write some code to do this for me.

I was thinking of using some sort of reflection or property on the validator but I could not see any to use.

My validators look like

```
public class MyValidator: AbstractValidator<myClass>
{
   public MyValidator()
       {
          RuleFor(a=>a.Name)
          .NotNull().WithMessage(s=> "Hello World");
       }
}
```

If someone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Comment: What will the documentation say that the C# code doesn't already say?

Comment: Your time is better spent on writing unit tests for the validators. FluentValidation has some extension methods that make testing easier: https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/testing.html

Comment: As well as tests my client wants a list of rules in an excel document. :(

Comment: Ok. I understand now. This might be an answerable question if you add that to your question text. Can you tell us more about what your client is expecting for documentation? Can you post the code you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

I have been unable to find a way to do this by interrogating the validator code, so I ended up reading and interpreting the validator files.  It is not the way I would like to do it but it allows me to meet the clients demands.

**Update July 2021**
I have had another look at this and there is a better way to do this, using reflection.  The multiple conditions for each rule, are held within a property called components.

```
 var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(AssemblyPath);
foreach (Type validatorType in assembly.GetTypes().Where(m => m.BaseType.Name.StartsWith("AbstractValidator")))
{
    var validatorClass = Activator.CreateInstance(validatorType, true);
    var rules = (IEnumerable)RefelctInstanceProperty(validatorClass, "Rules");
    var _innerCollection = (IEnumerable)ReflectInstanceField(rules, "_innerCollection");
    foreach (IValidationRule rule in _innerCollection)
    {
        var member = rule.Member;
        string propertyName = rule.Member.Name;
        var propertyType = rule.TypeToValidate.FullName;
        var modelType = rule.Member.DeclaringType.FullName;
        string expression = rule.Expression.ToString();
        foreach (FluentValidation.Internal.IRuleComponent component in rule.Components)
        {
            string errormessage = component.GetUnformattedErrorMessage();
            IPropertyValidator componentValidator = component.Validator;

            Console.WriteLine($"| {modelType.PadRight(50, ' ')} | {propertyName.PadRight(20, ' ')} | {propertyType.PadRight(30, ' ')} | {expression} | {errormessage} |");
            Console.WriteLine($"| {"".PadRight(73, ' ')} | {componentValidator.Name.PadRight(30, ' ')} |");
        }
    }
}
```

Working demo can be found on GitHub @ https://github.com/CodeTile/Test.FluentValidation.Validators

Comment: Honestly, probably the easiest if it's manageable. It is possible to get the info you want starting with `validator.CreateDescriptor()`, you get access to the properties that have rules, details of, the rule sets they are in etc but there is a lot of effort in building an overall picture of what the validator does. Then once you've got a method that does this for you, you'd then need a way to create an instance of all of the validators in your solution to run it against; I'd probably create a service provider and use scrutor to discover them all. A lot of effort for what is probably a one off.